# Grails unit tests - checking arguments when using demand on mock

Tags: grails, mocking, googlemock

I can test that a mock method is called using 'demand'. However, i would like to also make sure the expected arguments are passed to the method. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a simple `assert` within the `demand` closure will probably suffice.

```
def mockedBook = mockFor(Book)

mockedBook.demand.read { String author, String name ->
  assert author == 'Tolstoy'
  assert name == 'War and Peace'

  return true
}
```